# How to do string interpolation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, string-interpolation

I am trying to use string interpolation so that, given

```
var eruption1 = 112;
```

I can use

```
console.log("Eruption 1: {eruption1}");
```

instead of

```
console.log('Eruption 1: '+ eruption1);
```

However when I use either

```
console.log("Eruption 1: {eruption1}");
```

or

```
console.log('Eruption 1: {eruption1}');
```

I just get

```
Eruption 1: {eruption1}
```

instead of

```
Eruption 1: 112
```

How can I use string interpolation in javascript?