# String interpolation in Typescript with string read from file

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have read about [template strings](http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/template-strings.html) in Typescript. I'd like to know if I can use them when I've read a string from a file like this:

```
let xmlPayloadTemplate = fs.readFileSync('payload.xml', 'utf8');
```

If the `xmlPayloadTemplate` contains a placeholder like `${placeholder}`, is there a built-in way to perform the substitution so that I can do something like:

```
let variableMap = {'placeholder' : 'value' }
xmlPayloadTemplate.interpolate(variableMap)
```

?

I'm aware of [a similar question about string interpolation in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24850819/412834) but I'd like to know if there is a better way to do it in Typescript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TypeScript does string interpolation at compile-time and not run-time.

You'll need to find a way to do it at run-time. You could use [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24850874/188246) you linked to in your question or here's [another example](https://gist.github.com/padolsey/6008842).

Comment: Thanks to your link I found that Lodash offers a template function that I can use. I'll settle for that!

Answer (score 2):

Reinouts' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380101/string-interpolation-in-typescript-with-string-read-from-file#comment52661607_32380284) pointed me to Lodash library and it's [template](https://lodash.com/docs#template) function. Here is an example how to use it.

Add Lodash to your project:

```
$ npm install --save lodash
$ npm install --save @types/lodash
```

Then, in your .ts file:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";

let xmlPayloadTemplate = "Some text ${placeholder} and more text";

let variableMap = {placeholder: 'value' };

// use custom delimiter ${ }
_.templateSettings.interpolate = /\${([\s\S]+?)}/g;

// interpolate
let compiled = _.template( xmlPayloadTemplate );
let xmlPayloadCompiled = compiled( variableMap );

// show me
alert(xmlPayloadCompiled);
```